# Correct way of achieving this.class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose I have a class `Foo` in package `my.package` which contains some static fields.

I want to use reflection to get the values of those static fields.

I know I can write `my.package.Foo.class.getDeclaredField(...` but this is unsatisfactory as I'm hardcoding the class and package names.

I'd like to use `this.class.getDeclaredField(...` but this is invalid in Java even if called from within a non-static member function.

Is there a way?

Comment: Non-statically, you can use `this.getClass()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class inherits the instance method `Object#getClass()`. Invoke that to get your instance's corresponding `Class` object.

I don't know why you would do this inside `Foo` as `Foo` already knows its `static` fields and you'd have access to them at compile time directly.

Answer (score 0):

Non-statically, you can use `this.getClass()` to get the current class, as [@sotirios-delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) mentioned.

Statically, you can do this, though it is a bit ugly:

```
public static Class<?> getCurrentClassStatic() {
    try {
        return Class.forName(new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return null; //Shouldn't happen...
    }
}
```